# Changing foreach loops to Parallel.ForEach and weird bugs

Tags: c#

I have several loops that I wrote using the traditional syntax

```
foreach(x in xs) {....}
```

Some of these loops are pretty intensive in terms of computation and I just changed them using the parallel syntax like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(x, xs => {...});
```

I see a major increase in performance!! Now my question is this: Am I introducing bugs using parallel multithreading? I read that thread safety is complex and can create weird bugs; what should I be concerned about?

Comment: If you're just changing the loops without knowing if the code is thread safe or not then *yes you should be concerned!* The code will run in parallel, so basically you can't have shared data between the parallel loops.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Can you show me an example of what NOT to do?

Comment: Reading/writing shared data during the loop.

Comment: Do you have tests for these changes to show that you didn't break anything?

Comment: You left out the most important part; `{...}` <--- Important!

Comment: The question of, "what are all of the things that do/don't work in parallel" is too broad of a scope for a SO question.  If you provide one or two examples, asking whether they are safe would be an appropriate question.  *Entire books* are written on the subject of the question you've asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing shared state will most likely not produce the desired result. Simple example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    sum++;
}
```

change this to

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, i => { sum++; });
```

and you'll see `sum` will have some random value because multiple threads are reading/writing `sum`.

If you lock around the update, you'll solve the problem, but you'll essentially turn the operation into a sequential operation again.

You need to make sure that whatever happens in the loop is safe.

Microsoft Patterns and Practices did [a book](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) that explains all this and more. You should check that out before you simply change the code to use parallel loops.

Answer (score 2):

To say definitely - post your iterations/loops code.

But in generall, your iterations should be independent from each other and try to avoid shared state. Any shared resources accross parallel iterations resources could introduce bugs.

Also when your calculations are depending from some other calculations or parallel operations or loops better to use TPL task chaining, it also helps to avoid shared cross-thread resources.

More infromation and samples and patterns/anti-patterns are good described in free Microsoft book: Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4

Download it here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222